# didSelectItemAtIndexPath not working with custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have checked similar topic but none helped me. Basically, I wrote a custom `UICollectionViewCell`, and in the collectionView, the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`method is not fired when I tap any of them.

I rewrote my code to use the standard `UICollectionViewCell` and it works then. Can anyone help me with what I should override/change?

> Custom cell:

```
class UICollectionViewCellWithButton: UICollectionViewCell {

   var button = UIButton();

   override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame);

      button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton;        
      button.setTitle("", forState: UIControlState.Normal);        
      button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);        
      self.addSubview(button);      

   }

   required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder);
   }

   /* override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView?{
        return self;
   }*/
}
```

> Collection view:

```
class StartNodeViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var numberOfNodes = Int();
    private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell";
    var cellColor = true;
    var counter = 1;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();               

        self.navigationItem.title="Select start node";           
        self.collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCellWithButton.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell");    
    }        

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // 1
        return 1;
    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // 2
        return numberOfNodes;
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCellWithButton {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCellWithButton;

        cell.button.setTitle(counter.description, forState: UIControlState.Normal);
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
        counter++;
        return cell;
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        //super.collectionView(collectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath: indexPath);

        (collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UICollectionViewCellWithButton).button.setTitle("0", forState: UIControlState.Normal);
    }        
}
```

The code might be a little mess at this point because I tried anything I found.

Comment: How big are the cells? Is your button covering the whole thing and intercepting the touches?

Comment: You're right! The buttons are definitely covering it. Is there any way I can get the buttons to give up touch interception?

Comment: Why would you want them to do that? What do you want the buttons to do, and what do you want cell selection to do? Two different things?

Comment: the code currently stands as a placeholder of sorts. What I want to do is have didSelectItemAtIndexPath fired either when that button is touched or the cell itself, doesn't matter

Comment: Just put the code you would normally have in didSelectItemAtIndexPath in your button's action method. No need to have both firing.

Comment: Or, just get rid of the button. What's its purpose if you want it to do the same thing as cell selection?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1. Remove the constructor inside the `UICollectionViewCellWithButton`.
2. Put the button in the cell using the InterfaceBuilder
3. Change the return value of the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` to `UICollectionViewCell`.

And run it, it should be work. I hope this help you.

Comment: 1. which one? 2. I can't, this is a second view and the buttons are called dynamically. 3. That did not help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

@rdelmar answered me. I ended up switching the button for a label.